# how to delete a file with quote in file name

Tags: bash, shell

When I do `ls` in my directory, get bunch of these:

```
data.log".2015-01-22"
data.log".2015-01-23"
```

However when I do this:

```
rm: cannot remove `data.log.2015-01-22': No such file or directory
```

If I could somehow do something line `ls | escape quotes | xargs rm`

So yeah, how do I remove these files containing `"`?

**Update**

While most answer work. I was actually trying to do this:

```
ls | rm
```

So it was failing for some files. How can I escape a quote in a pipe after `ls`? Most of the answers actually addresses the manual manipulation of file which works. But I was asking about the escaping/replacing quotes after the `ls`. Sorry if my question was confusing.

Comment: `rm 'data.log".2015-01-22"'` should work

Comment: Asked and answered so many times you have to make an effort to avoid finding an answer.

Comment: thanks for contributing @jww that was really helpful. Takes an effort to say how many times question has been asked instead of helping, that's some next level

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you only need to do this once in a while interactively, use

```
rm -i -- *
```

and answer `y` or `n` as appropriate. This can be used to get rid of many files having funny characters in their name.

It has the advantage of not needing to type/escape funny characters, blanks, etc, since the shell globbing with `*` does that for you. It is also as short as it gets, so easy to memorize.

Comment: this works great by the way. much easier

Answer (score 5):

Use single quotes to quote the double quotes, or backslash:

```
rm data.log'"'*
rm data.log\"*
```

Otherwise, double quotes are interpreted by the shell and removed from the string.

### Answer to the updated question:

Don't process the output of `ls`. Filenames can contain spaces, newlines, etc.

Answer (score 4):

You could do like this.

```
find . -type f -name '*"*' -exec rm {} +
```

Answer (score 4):

If you have a particularly stubborn file that has all kinds of characters

For example

```
''$'\336\017\200\336\024\b''J'$'\336\017\220\336\024\b''V'$'\336\017\240\336\024\b''^'$'\336\017\260\336\024\b''f'$'\336\017\300\336\024\b''p'$'\336\017\320\336\024\b''y'$'\336\017\340\336\024\b\202\336\017\360\336\024\b\212\336\017\337\024\b\223\336\017\020\337\024\b\234\336\017'
```

If it were me, I'd forget dealing with interpolation of strings (unless you are really good at using special characters) and use the file index number, or inode.

For example, assume your culprit is in the current working directory, then the following procedure would work:

```
# visually inspect list of files with index numbers (inodes) for the culprit
ls -i .  
# remove the culprit by inode
find . -maxdepth 1 -inum <inode> -exec rm {} \;
```

and be done with it.

Answer (score 2):

Escape the quote with single quotes

```
$ touch '"  and spaces also "'
$ ls
"  and spaces also "
$ rm '"  and spaces also "'
$ ls
$
```

In your case:

```
$ rm 'data.log".2015-01-22"' 'data.log".2015-01-23"'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ls | rm
```

doesn't work because `rm` gets the files to remove from the command line arguments, not from standard input. You can use xargs to translate standard input to arguments.

```
ls | xargs -d '\n' rm
```

But to just delete the files you want, quote the part of the name containing the single quote:

```
rm 'data.log"'.*
```

Comment: `ls | xargs rm` will fail if file name contains spaces; and probably in many other cases too. `ls` is not meant to be parsed by programs.

Comment: I added a `-d` option to `xargs`, so now it will only fail if the filename contains a newline. But the wildcard is the better solution.

Comment: That's already much better! keep the comment here so that people can see it and be warned that it breaks with filenames containing newlines.

Answer (score 1):

1st - suggestion - modify the tool creating file names with quotes in them... :)

Try a little wild-char magic - using your tool of choice, i.e I would use `tr`:

```
ls | escape quotes | xargs rm  ## becomes something like:  
ls | tr "[\",']" '?' | xargs rm ## does not work on my system but this does:
rm -v $(ls *sing* *doub* | tr "[\",']" '?')
```

Output is:

```
removed `"""double"""'
removed `\'\'\'single\'\'\''
```

Now:

```
$ touch "'''single'''" '"""double"""'
$ ls -l *sing* *doub*
-rw-rw-r-- 1 dale dale 0 Feb 15 09:48 """double"""
-rw-rw-r-- 1 dale dale 0 Feb 15 09:48 '''single'''
```

If your patterns are consistent the other way might be to simplify:

```
$ rm -v *sing* *doub*
removed `\'\'\'single\'\'\''
removed `"""double"""'
```

For your example:

```
rm -v data.*${YEAR}-${MONTH}-${DAY}*  ## data.log".2015-01-22"  OR
rm -v data.*${YEAR}-${MONTH}-${DAY}?  ## data.log".2015-01-22"
```