# How to store file path in database using php?

Tags: php, mysql

I have two php pages adp3.php(form page) and adp4.php(uploads content to database)

adp3.php:

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <label>SUBJECT:</label><select name="subject">
 <?php 
$query="SELECT * FROM subject WHERE SyllabusID=".$batch1." and SemID=".$sems."";
$result=mysqli_query($con, $query);
//loop
foreach($result as $subject){
?>
<option value="<?php echo $subject['SubjectID']."-".$subject['SubjectName']; ?>"><?php echo $subject['SubjectName']; ?></option>
<?php
}
?>
  </select>
   <br>
DATE: <select name="date">
    <option>MAY/JUNE</option>
    <option>NOV/DEC</option>
    </select>

    <p color="white">YEAR: <input  type="varchar" name="year"/></p></br>

    <p color="white">PAPER LINK: <input  type="file" name="file"/></p></br>
         <br>
         <button formaction="adp4.php" class="btn-login">GO</button>
```

adp4:

```
<?php
$date =$_POST['date'];
$year=$_POST['year'];
$file=$_FILES['file'];

    if($date && $year)
    { mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("we couldnt connect");
       mysql_select_db("dbmsproj");
        $result=mysql_query("INSERT INTO paper(SubjectID,Date,Dlink) values('$subid','$date $year','$file')");

      ?>  <p color="white"><?php echo "Paper SUCCESSFULLY ADDED TO THE DATABASE";
    }
    else
    {?>
        <p color="white"><?php echo  "ALL FIELDS NEED TO BE FILLED ";
    }
        ?>
```

everything is getting entered correctly in db besides file path(shows "Array" in file path field).. please help

Update: (PROBLEM SOLVED) Thank you guys for helping me. My code is finally working . you guys are the **best**

Comment: you have to manualy put your file to your directory using `move_uploaded_file()` and then insert the path to database field

Comment: I wouldn't store the path, only the file names.  Paths can change, if you wind up moving things around at some point, you wont want to have to update all those records.  ( or use a symlink, yuck )  For example at my work we have 90k pdfs stored in the DB, we've migrated across 3 servers in the last 4 years. ( And one domain name )

Comment: Another thing I recomend, is renaming the files using a hash.  ( like sha1 ) then save it to the file system with a timestamp and hash `time().hash().pdf`  Then save the user's file name ( original name ) in the DB ( that way you can fake like it's named that ).  You wouldn't believe the crap PPL put in filenames, all kind of stuff that mess your URLs and what not up.  I even had someone put `'` or `"` in the filename, that was bad mojo.  for why see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28504839/how-to-delete-a-file-with-quote-in-file-name

Comment: Oh OK I'll try 

Comment: Thanks  now my code is finally working. You are the **best**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you check what are you inserting: 
by this.

```
print_r($_FILES["file"]);
```

Comment: Thanks you very much..  because of y'all my code is finally working

Answer (score 3):

Try using $_POST['file'] instead of using $_FILE since you just need to know the file path

**EDIT:**

As for the documentation, $_FILES[] returns an array which has all the information about the file you have uploaded.
Using this array you can get the temporary name with path of the file using

```
$file=$_FILES['file']['temp_name'];
```

The above code will provide you with the relevant temporary name of the uploaded file within the server

See also : [PHP Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php)

For further inspection these are the data stored within the array (As for the PHP Documentation):

```
$_FILES['userfile']['name']
```

The original name of the file on the client machine.

```
$_FILES['userfile']['type']
```

The mime type of the file, if the browser provided this information. An example would be "image/gif". This mime type is however not checked on the PHP side and therefore don't take its value for granted.

```
$_FILES['userfile']['size']
```

The size, in bytes, of the uploaded file.

```
$_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']
```

The temporary filename of the file in which the uploaded file was stored on the server.

```
$_FILES['userfile']['error']
```

The error code associated with this file upload.

Comment: That's great then! Always remember to follow the documentations. They mostly have everything you want to know

Comment: Yeah they do  thanks again for helping me. With this my php project got completed 

Answer (score 0):

check this may this can help.

```
$filePath = realpath($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]);
```

Answer (score -1):

If you access file name than you have to do like this

$file = $_FILES["file"]["name"];

Comment: But I want file path. 